# TypeScript types to restrict array values

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, type-safety, typesafe

Can I use TypeScript types to restrict array inputs to certain elements?

For example, if I wanted to create a type that is an array that could hold any number of elements, but the elements are restricted to the values: `"dog"`, `3`, and `true`, could I do this without allowing any other string, number, or boolean values?

Comment: Try this : `const list: Array<'dog' | 3 | true> = []`

Answer (score 0):

Using `type dogList = Array<"dog" | 3 | true>;` to define the type then assigning it to a variable with `const list1: dogList = ["dog", 3, true, true];` works properly.